# Internal Server Error on server switch

Tags: php

i have a website with this .htaccess file

```
**# $Id: .htaccess,v 1.3 2003/06/12 10:53:20 hpdl Exp 
#
# This is used with Apache WebServers
#
# For this to work, you must include the parameter 'Options' to
# the AllowOverride configuration
#
# Example:
#
# <Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
#   AllowOverride Options
# </Directory>
#
# 'All' with also work. (This configuration is in the
# apache/conf/httpd.conf file)

# The following makes adjustments to the SSL protocol for Internet
# Explorer browsers

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfDefine SSL>
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  </IfDefine>
</IfModule>

# If Search Engine Friendly URLs do not work, try enabling the
# following Apache configuration parameter
#
# AcceptPathInfo On

# Fix certain PHP values
# (commented out by default to prevent errors occuring on certain
# servers)
#
#<IfModule mod_php5.c>
#  php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
#  php_value register_globals 1
#</IfModule>**
```

now its geerating strang kind of errors i have switched my server the error line is
Server Requirement Error: register_globals is disabled in your PHP configuration. This can be enabled in your php.ini configuration file or in the .htaccess file in your catalog directory.
can some one help me to sort out this error

Comment: Is something unclear about the error message perhaps?

Comment: this is not a php issue in anyway in the future you should use apache for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
register_globals = "on”
```

set the above in your php.ini file then restart apache. Make sure to change this line and not just add it in the top or it will just get overwritten when it is set again below it.

the php.ini file is normally located in /etc/php.ini

Comment: register_globals = On
allow_url_fopen = On
safe_mode = Off this code is written inside the public_html/x_php.ini

Comment: but still same problem is there

Comment: Ok well then we can't really do anything for you until you give us some more information. The only other thing to try is uncomment the <IfModule mod_php5.c> block of code and see if that does it for some odd reason.

Comment: also just to be safe stop and start apache as apposed to just running a restart.

Comment: We have is an htaccess file and an error message that is not the right error message. if what you said is true about your php.ini you would not be getting this error. I just noticed you have two *'s before and at the end of your htaccess is this actually there or a typo?

Comment: I see you said that code is in public_html/x_php.ini in an edit are you sure that this file is loaded in on your new server? that is not the default name or location for php.ini files and is not configured to load in by default.